# Passing pointer address to global variable

Tags: c, variables, pointers, global

I have a pointer which is being passed into a function like so:

```
unsigned char globalvar;

int functionexp(unsigned char *buff){
    globalvar = buff;
    //start interrupt
    //wait for end of interrupt
    //pass original pointer back with updated results
}

void __attribute__((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _DMA2Interrupt(void) {
    globalvar = somedata;
}
```

And I have an interrupt which collects data that I need to pass into said pointer. What I want to do is create a global dummy variable and copy the original pointer (bufF) address into this global variable, so when I write data to the global variable which I can access within the interrupt (as I can't pass the original pointer into the interrupt) it also updates the values in the original pointer.

My example shows the basis of what I want to do, but without the pointer syntax. Could someone please show me how to do this, please!

Comment: Are pointers and `int` the same size on your platform (perhaps a dumb question on my part, but had to ask).

Comment: Yes, sorry. The example was quickly written just to show what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @ritchie888 How is `globalvar = buff;` supposed to work? Why not a pointer.

Comment: It isn't. As I say, this isn't real code, it's just to give an understanding of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm asking how I would go about making a global variable 'clone' of my original pointer, so by changing the global I'm also changing the original pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear.
My first interpretation of what I thought you're trying to do, it would be something like this:

```
unsigned char **buffptr;

int functionexp(unsigned char *buff){
    buffptr = &buff;
    //start interrupt
    //wait for end of interrupt
    //pass original pointer back with updated results
    // after this point, the value of buffptr is completely useless,
    // since buff doesn't exist any more!
}

void __attribute__((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _DMA2Interrupt(void) {
    *buffptr = somedata;  
    // this changes the 'buff' variable in functionexp
}
```

On the other hand you could simply mean this:

```
unsigned char *globalbuff;

int functionexp(unsigned char *buff){
    globalbuff = buff;
    //start interrupt
    //wait for end of interrupt
    //pass original pointer back with updated results
}

void __attribute__((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _DMA2Interrupt(void) {
    globalbuff[0] = somedata;
    // this changes data inside the buffer pointed to by the 'buff' 
    // variable in functionexp
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried both and the second example is the one that worked. Didn't know it could be that simple. Thanks again.

Comment: The first example is wrong. You are assigning data to pointer. But maybe that is what OP wanted.